# Is Ignite FieldsQueryCursor throughput non-linear?

Tags: performance, ignite

I’m running an Ignite version 2.15 client node and a data node locally, eager keepBinary SqlFields queries over an ATOMIC cache.

Query is a simple select from, no clauses.

Test data set is 15 MBytes, 3500 records, about 60 fields each.

This is what I get on cursor.getAll():

| projection | latency (msec) | data (bytes) | rate (MByte/sec) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 fields | 23 | 300 K | 13 |
| 20 fields | 38 | 3 M | 79 |
| all | 80 | 14 M | 175 |

I expected constant throughput from the server, eg if 175 MByte/sec was it, i'd have gotten this instead:

| projection | latency (msec) | data (bytes) | rate (MByte/sec) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 fields | 1.7 | 300 K | 175 |
| 20 fields | 17 | 3 M | 175 |
| all | 80 | 15 M | 175 |

**UPD** ran this on a 80GB data set in a cluster with 3 data nodes

| projection | rate (MByte/sec) |
| --- | --- |
| 3 fields | 51 |
| 20 fields | 283 |

Is cursor throughput in Ignite non-linear in relation to projection width? If yes, why?

Comment: I suppose it could be a matter of measurement inaccuracy on such a short duration and some constant delay for query in each of measurements. What if execute those test on a way larger store?

Comment: Naturally there is some O(1) complexity to parse the query, plus O(N) where N = row count, plus O(M * N) where M = column count. So it is not linear when you vary M.

Comment: @gdomo upd, tested on a larger scale

Comment: @PavelTupitsyn i don't see it; all tests have the same row count, won't that reduce O(MN) to O(cM)?

Comment: I think that most of the time is spent by row page lookup, but when we find required page it doesn't really matter how many fields we have to read (so long whole row fit in single page). That's why we don't see x20 difference between 3 fields and all fields